# How to edit column width of an Excel report which was created by an Access query?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to automate a process that will auto adjust the column width of an Excel report. This Excel report is being generated by a query in Access. So, I can't put VBA code in Excel file itself. I need to put VBA code or something else in Access so that whenever I run the query I get auto adjusted column width in output Excel report. I have tried few things but none are working.

```
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("qryFT").Columns.Autofit
'acOutpotquery.Select
'Column("A:A").Select
'Selection.EntireColumn.Autofit
```

Comment: Commented-out code rarely works as expected

Comment: I copy pasted my code directly. I commented it out because it was not working and I don't like useless code in module. If you can help please do, have a good day otherwise.

Comment: Surely your code has a reference to the `Workbook` object it creates - assuming that's called `theWorkbook`, have you tried `theWorkbook.Worksheets("qryFT").Columns.EntireColumn.Autofit`?

Comment: Tried. Not working. I think problem here is not with the code but in the transition it has to do from Access to Excel. I am writing code in Access for Excel. Does it sound logical?

Comment: I'm confused how you could use any of the commented-out commands (except the second) in Excel VBA. If your output is in a structured Excel table, you can just set the Adjust Column Width property in the table's properties.

Comment: I suggest you paste the code that you are using - then we will have a chance of being able to work out what change you need.  Otherwise we will have to take wild guesses as to how you are referring to your workbook object.

Comment: And if you aren't using a structured table with a data connection to Access, you maybe should be. Data > Connections > From Access.

Comment: Why does it need to be *generated by a query*? Can you not just connect the worksheet to the Access database? oh, Doug beat me to it lol

Comment: FWIW - This is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/42985568/6535336  (I **knew** I had seen those statements before!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create buttons on Excel report that is being generated by Access query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985568/how-to-create-buttons-on-excel-report-that-is-being-generated-by-access-query)

Comment: @Hosch250 - That's strange - I thought you could only mark things as duplicates if the other question had been answered.

Comment: Huh, I just flagged it.

Comment: Thanks to those who tried to help. I got the answer. Thanks to those as well who were more interested in finding similar questions rather than answering, you guys made me realize only you can help yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've already created the Excel object?  Let's call it MyXL

```
myxl.workbooks.open filename:={path to your Excel sheet}    
myxl.activeworkbook.sheets(1).columns(x).autofit
```

where x = column number

Comment: Or if you want to autofit all columns:  `myxl.activeworkbook.sheets(1).usedrange.columns.autofit`

Comment: Thanks for helping!